# How to stretch or compress a spiral cylinder

Tags: rendering, animation, scripting, armature, bezier-curves

I have a cylinder-like spiral object as a `.STL` file (figure). We want to animate compressing and stretching this cylinder (figure). How can this be done?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edited:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would try it with 2 shapekeys:

- In the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Shapekeys*, create 2 shapekeys, keep the second selected.
- Go in *Edit* mode, enable the *Proportional Editing* mode, *Linear* option, select the top vertices of your object, adjust the influence circle, pull up so that your object looks like your second image.
- Back in *Object* mode, play with the shapekey *Value*, push it up to 1 if you want the object to be fully spread.
- You might need to make some vertices adjustments for one or the other shapekey in *Edit* mode, in that case deactivate the *Proportional Editing*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. There are some issues regarding this method:

Comment: Highlighted edges are not detached in my geometry(I added the image in the "Edited" part of the question). I also added two other images which present pulling the top vertices with two different influence circles. These two images show the issue of detachment.

Comment: so you need to redesign your shape to make it possible. Maybe with some rips (V) on the edge loops you could cut it but I'm not sure, maybe share your file...

Comment: Thanks. I added the file just after the question.

Comment: I think it's a bit too hard to start with the current topology   ;)  you should entirely rethink your object to make the animation possible, starting for example from a spirale curve like I've done